# How to read JSON with multiple key value pair

Tags: javascript, json

On AJAX request response is following :

```
[  {"status":{"login":"invalid"}},
   {"user":{"username":false,"pwd":false}}
]
```

How to read values in Jquery.

Comment: Dot notation or bracket notation.

Comment: `data[0].status.login` for example.

Comment: data[1].user[0].username

Comment: Thanks it worked....

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse(string)` to get an `Object`.
After that you can access values as default:

```
var json = JSON.parse(res.data)
console.log(json.status.login)
```

Comment: This wouldn't work with the given example

Comment: Well, im not sure what he wants because of ungiven examples.. but the second line of code counts and the statement to treat it like an object

Comment: It's an array, you cannot access .status of an array, only of the items